# Regular Expression to convert m4 code to jinja code

Tags: python, regex, linux, unix, regex-group

I've been working for a few days for work and I don't know how to convert these lines of code:

```
m4_define(\-:PM_Requirement:-/,\-:m4_dnl
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0815</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0816</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0817</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0818</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0819</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0820</id><version>1</version></requirement>:-/)
```

to:

```
{%- set Requirement = "<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0815</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0816</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0817</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0818</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0819</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0820</id><version>1</version></requirement>"
-%}
```

I tried the following regex in sed:

```
sed -i -E 's/m4_define\(\\-:PM_Requirement:-\/,\\-:m4_dnl([(\r\n|\r|\n)\W[:alnum:]_]+):-\/\)
```

i tried debugg in https://regex101.com/r/ExM1Qx/1

Could anyone give me a bit of help, what i could do to make it work?

I tried to replace \W with something else, but did not find the right combination that could be accepted, i don't know the "flavor" of regex that is used here

The above command I used is for PCRE (PHP <7.3)

Anyone has some good idea about this ?

PS: Other commands that work look like this:

```
sed -i -E 's/m4_define\(\\-:PM_([[:alnuum:]_]+):-\/,\\:-([[:alnum:]_\/]+):-\/\)  {%- set \1 = "\2" -%}/'
```

The result is this (convert m4 in jinja):

m4 code:

```
m4_define(\-:PM_ImplementationFile:-/,\-:Crypto_1_Test:-/)
```

to  Jinja code:

```
{%- set ImplementationFile = "Crypto_1_Test" -%}
```

Comment: You say you tried `sed` to solve the problem, but you ask for a Python solution. Please provide your Python attempt then.

Comment: Yes, i'm not sure what type of "flavor" of regex i used. I thought it was python, I corrected the statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sed` you might use

```
sed -E ':a;$!{N;ba};s|m4_define\(\\-:PM_([[:alnum:]_]+):-/,\\-:([[:alnum:]_]*\r?\n)?([[:print:][:space:]]*):-/\)|{%- set \1 = "\3" -%}|' file
```

See a [first sed demo](https://tio.run/##VY1PC4IwHIa/ypLEPzVC6jQJD1HQoejQzY0x9RcKOodbh3B@dtOCoOvz8D5vJnQ5jpCXLcJH5DQ7XsCjkuBTTG4Xfm5UDQ1II0zVylNVA8Gb9eQO3UuZlkf8DtpMLHCQRRqKueIRES8X/TXOxBBr@2tSn36rfpoSUctnQxhnq@CTnMwfDmmXUBkkM1RdJQ1hKdFK5EAYC@cNDWzv4unUIBqhPXLo1kHYHaw3jm8) and [second sed demo](https://tio.run/##rZJLb8IwEITv/RVuBCKBWiH0RR03HCrUE6iqeosty5CtsESc1A6VKsJvT52ivm4cclvN7nx7mFlJu2kaWG8KhOfIy69EBq9Kg88weVqIZ3jbKQM56Irg8MKJ7YXenlHzu0moypL5o3gwH2VViBewlRhPo2saOp2@g7Gq0ElEw@@Rhn/dp7BuOmTddsiadsi66441GZ/IcqEGHqqRhazNf0Bk3DvfL@OVPMS2/mkD89mxD36aErnVu5xwwUfBVyfc5p88ZGbGdDBrxdIo1xyeElvKNRDOh62HBfW@j93TCrEI3SOPXXoI9w/1oGk@AQ).

Output for the first example

```
{%- set Requirement = "<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0815</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0816</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0817</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0818</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0819</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0820</id><version>1</version></requirement>" -%}
```

Output for the second example:

```
{%- set ImplementationFile = "Crypto_1_Test" -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the input consists of M4 macros you can use M4 to do the replacement.

With the following file `macros.m4`

```
define(m4_dnl, `dnl')dnl
define(m4_define, {%- set regexp($1, \(PM_\)?\(.*\), \2) = "$2" -%})dnl
changequote(\-:, :-/)dnl
```

run

```
m4 macros.m4 inputfile
```

to get (nearly) the requested output. The only difference is that with the first input, the trailing  `-%}` is not in a separate line.

```
{%- set Requirement = "<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0815</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0816</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0817</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0818</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0819</id><version>1</version></requirement>
<requirement><id>EG_Crypto_Test_0820</id><version>1</version></requirement>" -%}
```

**Explanation**

The macro `m4_define` is defined to generate the requested output from the macro arguments.

The `regexp` macro inside `m4_define`'s replacement is used to remove a leading `PM_` in the first macro argument `$1` if present. (The second macro argument `$2` is used unchanged.)

The `changequote` macro defines the unusual quote characters `\-:` and `:-/` used in the input data.